# cannot delete my own home directory /home/<userid>

Tags: windows-7, cygwin

I have a weird situation. I was using cygwin (under win7) just fine and loved it.
My win7 machine crashed so I had to reinstall the OS (over the old one). Fine so far.

Now I still have the old paths `/home/<old-user-id>`. But I can't run the files, nor can delete that directory ...all this mess because my `<old-user-id>` is same as my `<new-user-id>`

How do I delete the old paths, etc? I am the Administrator of the win7 machine.

Comment: You can't delete it?  What happens when you try?

Answer (score 0):

Longshot, but have you tried uninstalling Cygwin?

In essence delete `C:\cygwin` and reinstall.